# SQL Query for counting >2 orders in a particular year

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables. `salesreps` with columns: SRepID, SRepName, SRepPhone

`orders` with columns: OrderID, CustomerID, SRepID, OrderDate

I need to return all the SRepName who have handled at least two orders in the year 2019.

I am completely lost on this one and would love a push in the right direction.

I'm doing this in SQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SRepName from salesReps
inner join Orders on salesReps.SRepID = orders.SRepID
where orderDate >= '2019-01-01' and orderDate <  '2020-01-01'
group by sRepName
having count(OrderId) >1
```

Comment: Great! I just added the date part from the GMB's response and it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Monica lol, I just noticed that I missed that. Added it in to make the answer 100% correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to count the number of orders per sales rep:

```
select s.*
from salesrep s
where (
    select count(*) 
    from orders o 
    where 
        o.repId = s.sRepId
        and o.orderDate >= '2019-01-01'
        and o.orderDate <  '2020-01-01'
 ) >= 2
```

Or you can use aggregation. This requires you to enumerate the columns that you want to return, but also gives you the possibility to use aggregate functions on the orders:

```
select
    s.sRepId,
    s.sRepName,
    count(*) no_orders,
    max(o.OrderDate) last_order_date
from salesrep s
inner join orders o on o.repId = s.sRepId
where o.orderDate >= '2019-01-01' and o.orderDate <  '2020-01-01'
group by s.sRepId, s.sRepName
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Wow, that looks really advanced! Is there a more basic way to accomplish this? I made a typo in my original post (RepID should have been SRepID for orders). Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
select SRepName
      ,count(OrderID)
  from salesreps s
 inner join orders o
    on s.SRepID = o.SRepID
 where year(OrderDate) = '2019'
group by SRepName
having count(OrderID) >= 2
```